# Hindi Translate Script Api

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-translate, hindi

I am using google language translate script api. I just want to keep Hindi option in the dropdown 'Select Language'. How to remove rest of the languages from the dropdown except Hindi.

Script Used is mentioned below :

```
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
                                      new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en'}, 'google_translate_element');
                                    }
                                </script>

                                <script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

How could I achieve this ?